# Merge objects in same array on single key

Tags: json, jq

I have an array of JSON objects formatted as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "grass",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/12/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "poison",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/4/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Ivysaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "ice",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/10/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "electric",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/8/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Venusaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "ground",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/2/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "rock",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/3/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that these are pairs of separate objects that appear sequentially in a JSON array, with each pair sharing an `id` field. This pattern repeats several hundred times in the array. What I need to accomplish is to "merge" each `id`-sharing pair into one object. So, the resultant output would be

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "grass",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/12/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "poison",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/4/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Ivysaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "ice",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/10/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "electric",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/8/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "names": [
      {
        "name": "Venusaur",
        "language": {
          "name": "en",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/language/9/"
        }
      },
    ],
    "types": [
      {
        "slot": 1,
        "type": {
          "name": "ground",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/2/"
        }
      },
      {
        "slot": 2,
        "type": {
          "name": "rock",
          "url": "http://myserver.com:8000/api/v2/type/3/"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I've gotten these objects to appear next to each other via the `group_by(.id)` command, but I'm at a loss as to how I should actually combine them. I'm very much still a novice with `jq` so I'm a bit overwhelmed with the amount of possible solutions.

Comment: Show us a complete JSON to work with and not snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note: The following assumes that the data shown in the Q have been corrected so that they are valid JSON.]

The merging you want can be achieved by object addition (`x + y`).  For example, given the two JSON objects as shown in the question (i.e., as a stream), you could write:

```
jq -s '.[0] + .[1]'
```

However, since the question also indicates these objects are actually in an array, let's next consider the case of an array with two objects.  In that case, you could simply write:

```
jq add
```

Finally, if you have an array of arrays each of which is an array of objects, you could use `map(add)`. Since you don't have a very large array, you could simply write:

```
group_by(.id) | map(add)
```

Please note that jq defines object addition in a non-commutative way.  Specifically, there is a bias towards the right-most key.

Comment: Thanks! The solution works but I need it to work on more than just two items (see the edit). So the output would be `.[0]` and `.[1]` merged together, followed by `.[2]` and `.[3]` merged together, and so on.

Comment: You mentioned you'd already used `group_by` so I assumed you could fill in the details.  Anyway, I've included a simple solution using `group_by`.

Comment: I figured it out -- turns out that you have to do `group_by(.id)[]` (note the `[]`) in order for the object pairs to actually be put in their own array. After that, it was as simple as piping to `{}` and choosing the fields I want from `.[0]` and `.[1]`.

Comment: That gives you a stream, whereas your Q specified an array.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness. I looked into the differences between the two and it would seem so. I'll accept your answer since it does answer the original question, which was just poorly formed due to a lack of understanding of `jq`.